# How to write a Unit Test case in c# without using the Operation context?

Tags: c#, automation, testcase, operationcontext, weboperationcontext

In My Project i have a method PreAction() which is used in all the Methods. PreAction() contains the Operation context object  i.e

```
OperationContext currentContext = OperationContext.Current
```

So when am trying to Invoke a Method X in that method I am using the PreAction() Method. So as the operation context is of service model, I am getting an exception indicating that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

So how to overcome this scenario ? Is there a way to use the Mcoking and can we resolve this scenario?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need an integration test rather then a unit test.
In this case you should create a proxy of your service and validate the returned result and perhaps the persisted result.

But apart from that you best create a series of unit tests on your logic layer. All these classes should be build in a way that they don't depends on the PreActions of your serive.

Make sure you can stub or mock all your depending properties and interfaces.